# Intuit Partner Platform - Can't add an invoice because Item ID is unknown

Tags: c#, .net, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to insert an invoice via IPP into a blank Quickbooks store. The insert will always fail because the Item's ID for the Invoice line item does not exist. I have been trying multiple paths to code around this with no success. I thought I could query for the Items and if it cannot find the one I am looking for It will create it. I cannot seem to get this to work. Can I just build an Invoice with a new Item I have created?

I currently build the invoice like this: (the problem is the line that starts with "object[] invoiceItemValues")
            Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.InvoiceHeader invoiceHeader = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.InvoiceHeader();
            invoiceHeader.ARAccountName = "Accounts Receivable";
            invoiceHeader.BillAddr = physicalAddress;
            invoiceHeader.CustomerName = customer.Name;
            invoiceHeader.DocNumber = (invoiceMaxId).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
            invoiceHeader.TaxAmt = salesTax;
            invoiceHeader.TotalAmt = amount;

```
        List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.InvoiceLine> listLine = new List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.InvoiceLine>();


        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemsChoiceType2[] invoiceItemAttributes = { Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemsChoiceType2.ItemId, Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemsChoiceType2.UnitPrice, Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemsChoiceType2.Qty };
        object[] invoiceItemValues = { new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.IdType() { idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.idDomainEnum.QB, Value = "2" }, amount, new decimal(1) };



        var invoiceLine = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.InvoiceLine();
        invoiceLine.Amount = amount;
        invoiceLine.AmountSpecified = true;
        invoiceLine.Desc = "test " + date.ToShortDateString(); // TODO: This will need to hold the additional fields
        invoiceLine.ItemsElementName = invoiceItemAttributes;
        invoiceLine.Items = invoiceItemValues;
        invoiceLine.ServiceDate = date;
        invoiceLine.ServiceDateSpecified = true;
        listLine.Add(invoiceLine);

        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Invoice invoice = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Invoice();
        invoice.Header = invoiceHeader;
        invoice.Line = listLine.ToArray();
```

This is the error I get: "Validation for txn_line_rec.item_id INVALID key = 30 domain=QB enum = Item"

Here is what tries to query Items, but also requires IDs.

```
ItemQuery qbdItemQuery = new ItemQuery();
qbdItemQuery.Items = new object[] { new IdSet() { Id = new IdType[] { new IdType() { idDomain = idDomainEnum.NG, Value = "79841" } } } };
qbdItemQuery.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType4[] { ItemsChoiceType4.ListIdSet };
List<Item> ItemQueryResult = qbdItemQuery.ExecuteQuery<Item>(context).ToList<Item>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the sample in QBO, similarly you can code for QBD-
    Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Invoice invoice = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Invoice();

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.InvoiceHeader invoiceHeader = new     Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.InvoiceHeader();
invoiceHeader.DocNumber = "AUTO_GENERATE";
invoiceHeader.TxnDate = new DateTime(2013, 09, 04);
invoiceHeader.TxnDateSpecified = true;
invoiceHeader.CustomerId = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.IdType() { idDomain =     Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = "12" };
invoiceHeader.SubTotalAmt = 100;
invoiceHeader.SubTotalAmtSpecified = true;
invoiceHeader.TotalAmt = 100;
invoiceHeader.TotalAmtSpecified = true;

invoice.Header = invoiceHeader;

Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.InvoiceLine invoiceLine = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.InvoiceLine();
invoiceLine.Desc = "Description";
invoiceLine.Amount = 100;
invoiceLine.AmountSpecified = true;
invoiceLine.Taxable = false;
invoiceLine.TaxableSpecified = true;
invoiceLine.ItemsElementName = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemsChoiceType2[] {     Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemsChoiceType2.ItemId,     Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemsChoiceType2.UnitPrice, Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemsChoiceType2.Qty };
invoiceLine.Items = new object[] { new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.IdType() { idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = "30" }, 100m, 1m };

invoice.Line = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.InvoiceLine[] { invoiceLine };

Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Invoice addedInvoice = dataService.Add<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Invoice>(invoice);
```

Edit:
To create item-

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Item qboItem = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Item();                          
                        qboItem.Name = "nemoitem11";
                        qboItem.Desc = "Itemdesc";
                        qboItem.UnitPrice = new Money() ;
                        qboItem.UnitPrice.Amount = 20;
                        qboItem.IncomeAccountRef = new AccountRef();
                        qboItem.IncomeAccountRef.AccountId = new IdType() { idDomain = idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = "1" };
                        Item resultItem = commonService.Add(qboItem) as Item;
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing the same thing. "invoiceLine.Items = new object[] { new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.IdType() { idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = "30" }, 100m, 1m };". Thats an ID of 30.

Comment: This is the error I get: "Validation for txn_line_rec.item_id INVALID key = 30 domain=QB enum = Item"

Comment: I'm passing an existing item's ID here. For creating and retrieving item, please see the docs- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/item  Are you doing that anywhere?

Comment: That sort of gets to the heart of my problem. Querying items seems to also require IDs and without it I can't get results. I added the basis for my code for that above.

Comment: Also does that "invoiceHeader.DocNumber = "AUTO_GENERATE";" actually work? I get an error.

Comment: Please go through the docs. You will get all information there. Auto_Generate works only for QBO. The following works like retrieve all too - Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemQuery qbdItemQuery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemQuery();
                            IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item> qbdItems = qbdItemQuery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item>(context) as IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item>;

Comment: Thank you. This helps me greatly. The documentation is all but unreadable and largely broken with dead links in it.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post the broken links? I will get them corrected.